# maven - refer to local-settings .xml

Tags: java, maven

I have a local-settings.xml in my project base directory inside the .mvn folder . When I do clean install , maven is not refering to this file. How can I refer to this file without the -s option.

My directory structure is exactly like in this question : [Create project-specific Maven settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43156870/create-project-specific-maven-settings)

Comment: did you set `M2_HOME` ?

Comment: Yes.. When i do mvn -s <pathof the settings.xml in the project> install it is working fine. But when i do mvn clean install i'm getting error in downloading jar i mentioned in my local-settings.xml

Comment: You simply can't refer a settings.xml file in `.mvn` cause the settings.xml should be located in `$HOME/.m2/` or you have to give it explicitly via command line `-s ..` furthermore settings `M2_HOME` does not help...furthermore is deprecated...

Comment: But i want to share this settings.xml file to the team. So is there a way to execute the settings.xml while we do mvn clean install instead of mvn -s ?

Comment: I have resolved the issue by creating a maven.config file in the base directory of the project added these lines to point my settings.xml and settings-security.xml when I do "mvn clean install".

--settings ./.mvn/settings.xml -Dsettings.security=./.mvn/settings-security.xml

Answer (score 1):

You have to check what settings are maven taking during the deployment of the artifacts by using this command:

```
mvn help:effective-settings
```

Sometimes it can happen that you are using local settings and global settings (taking first the provided by the maven installation and then the provided by the repository), but maven is not recognizing both. With this command, you can verify the actual settings maven is taking during the deployment. In addition, you can locate the actual file maven is taking and, as a consequence, modify the file properly (with vim, for example) according to the configuration needed by the server.

Remember that there are two locations where a settings.xml file may live:

1. Maven installation directory

   $M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml
2. User-specific settings file

   ~/.m2/settings.xml

> If both files exists, their contents gets merged, with the user-specific settings.xml being dominant. https://maven.apache.org/settings.html