# Maven with user settings.xml and project-specific settings.xml

Tags: maven

I have several projects which point to different internal repositories.  Users on one project might not be able to see the repository on the other project, so I need a project specific `settings.xml` for each project.

[Create project-specific Maven settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43156870/create-project-specific-maven-settings) indicates that I can do this by creating a `MVN_ROOT/.mvn/maven.config` with

> --settings ./.mvn/settings.xml

and then putting the repository information inside `MVN_ROOT/.mvn/settings.xml`.

That seems to work and I can add those files to git and other users can use the repository automatically.

However, the repositories require validation, which requires that `settings.xml` contain something like

```
...
<server>
  <id>repo-proj-1</id>
  <username>me</username>
  <password>secret</password>
</server>
<server>
  <id>repo-proj-2</id>
  <username>my.name</username>
  <password>secure</password>
</server>
...
```

Obviously, I do not want to put this information into the git repository.   `~/.m2/settings.xml` is the obvious place to put that information.  However, it appears that I can only have one user settings file, as my login information is not picked up when I try to build.

Is there a way to use both settings files?

This needs to work on Mac, Linux and Windows, so something like `<xs:include>~/.m2/settings.xml</xs:include>` (XML include, probably not the right syntax) won't work as `~/.m2` is not usually the right location on Windows.

We are using Maven 3, and if a specific recent version is required, we can require users to upgrade to that version.

Comment: Does https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html help?

Comment: Why are using different repositories? Violates the idea of a repository manager...

Answer (score 1):

What about to treat the secrets as environment variables?

```
<server>
  <id>repo-proj-2</id>
  <username>${user}</username>
  <password>${pass}</password>
</server>
```

You can set them then via your build tool:

```
mvn -s ./build/settings.xml -Duser=xxx -Dpass=xxx clean install
```

Comment: Depending on shell settings, this leaves passwords in command history which can be persisted to disk unencrypted.

Comment: @user944849 the build machine must know the password anyway, even when encrypted, the master password must be given. It depends on the tool. We're using docker images for a pipeline run, the instance is destroyed after the build process finishes.

Comment: destroying the instance ensures the passwords are not persisted. A naive approach could leave the passwords unprotected, and my comment was merely encouraging folks to consider this.

Comment: If the variables are `PROJ-2.USER` and similar, then they can be set in `.bashrc` (or some file sourced by that), which seems to be almost as secure as storing them in `.m2/settings.xml`.  (If some one can see my environment variables, then they can probably also see the files on my system.).

Answer (score 0):

There should be a central repository which contains SNAPSHOT's and an other one which contains releases and a group in a repository manager which combines them for consuming. This should be configured in a `settings.xml` located either in Users home directory or in the configuration of your CI server.

Deployment to repositories should only being done by a CI Server never by a developer.

In the CI server you should correctly setup the credentials to be hosted by the CI Server (Jenkins: Credentials Store) etc.

If you need separate `settings.xml` by project it is a design problem in your setup's...and will cause many issues.

The separation of different projects is a basic thing in a Maven repository which is called coordinate which is a combination of groupId and artifactId plus version.

In general a `settings.xml` should be located only in the users home directory which contains users credentials if needed (as already mentioned combined with encryption).