# Is possible to have 2 settings.xml for a single maven home folder?

Tags: maven

I am having 2 projects. As per the requirement, I have to maintain the repos separately and some configuration also different.

I don't have permissions to install one more maven installation folder in my lap.

Is possible to have 2 settings.xml for a single maven installation home folder? (I would like to maintain like settings_A.xml and settings_B.xml in different locations).

Is it valid? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Check this https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html

Comment: not for an "installation"/"user", but you can start (each) `mvn` command with custom settings...

Answer (score 3):

yes you can point to a custom settings.xml per use and pass it as argument to Maven as following:

```
mvn --settings YourOwnSettings.xml clean install
```

or use shorter form:

```
mvn -s YourOwnSettings.xml clean install
```

you can also use project specific settings.xml configuration that explained in other stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43156870/create-project-specific-maven-settings)